# How to connect MDB with activation specifications

Tags: java, websphere, ejb, ibm-mq, message-driven-bean

I want to create one message queue consuming code using activation specifications and deploy into the websphere server.

I saw some code available with jboss.but,i want in IBM websphere server.

Previously,i done consuming with listener port and using ejb-jar.xml and ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi.

Now,i didn't no how to use activation specifications with XML and xmi files.is that right or not.Can anyone please,share the activation specifications code with bindings file and I want to deploy in websphere.
Thanks in advance

I need activation specifications with suitable binding or any sample project

Comment: Does either of these tutorials help?  https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-reactive-messaging-with-open-liberty-jms-jakarta/     or    https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-reactive-messaging-with-open-liberty-smallrye-amqp/

Answer (score 0):

#### Deployment

I think the harder part of this is configuring the activation spec that you need to "bind" to during deployment.

For that I'd link you to the WebSphere Knowledge Center:

- [Configuring a default messaging (SIBus) activation spec](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=provider-configuring-activation-specification-default-messaging)
- [Configuring an MQ activation spec](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=provider-creating-activation-specification-mq-messaging)

#### Development / Java coding

The Java implementation itself is fairly straightforward.  You might look at [this](https://github.com/WASdev/sample.jms.server/blob/master/src/main/java/wasdev/sample/jms/mdb/SampleMDB.java) example (though it's embedded in a Liberty sample repository).

#### Learn More

The high-level [MDB topic](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=applications-message-driven-beans-automatic-message-retrieval) in the Knowledge Center is also a good starting point.

Comment: In my project,i am using websphere mq message provider and using websphere application server instead of Liberty profile.is that right to use activation specifications with websphere application server

Comment: Yes, the documentation I linked to was for (traditional) WebSphere Application Server.   The .java coding of the MDB will basically be the same across Liberty and traditional WebSphere, but the process of defining the MQ resources, and administering and deploying the app and binding to those resources is what's different vs. Liberty.